# Function argument function cannot operate with array

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I was trying to make a functional bucket sort array in c with a variable funtion parameter in order to sort each bucket, so I tried to pass the *bubblesort* algorithm but it doesn't seems to do anything with each bucket, my question is: What am I doing wrong?, at my first glance it seems that there aren't mistakes in my code: (sorry for the mess)

```
void bubblesort (int arr[], unsigned char size) {
    size /= sizeof(int);
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    for (unsigned char j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
    if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        arr[j]   = arr[j] + arr[j+1],
        arr[j+1] = arr[j] - arr[j+1],
        arr[j]   = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
}

/* More sorting algorithms */

void bucketsort (int arr[], unsigned char size, unsigned char n, void sort(int[],unsigned char)) {
    // to be fixed
    size /= sizeof(int); int *bucket[n]; unsigned char s[n];
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < n; i++) s[i] = 0, bucket[i] = NULL;
    int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
    for (unsigned char i = 1; i < size; i++) { 
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
    } for (unsigned char i = 0; i < size; i++)
        s[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)]++,
        bucket[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)] = (int*)realloc(bucket[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)],s[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)]*sizeof(int)),
        bucket[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)][s[n*(arr[i]-min)/(max-min+1)]-1] = arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {for (int j = 0; j < s[i]; j++) printf("%d ",bucket[i][j]); printf("\n");}
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < n; i++) sort(bucket[i],s[i]), fflush(NULL);
    for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < s[i]; j++) arr[index++] = bucket[i][j];
}

int main (void) {
    int a[] = {3,6,4,9,1,7,5,8,2,0};
    bucketsort(a,sizeof(a),4,bubblesort);
    for (signed char i = 0; i < (signed char)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)); i++) printf("%d, ",a[i]);
 }
```

In my function parameter I´ve tried replacing the *[]* with * but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `bucketsort( a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a), 4, bubblesort );` looks suspicious, but you adjust it in the called function, so its valid.

Comment: ... and you adjust it again in the `bubblesort` function, so it's not valid. The `size` parameter to both `bubblesort` and `bucketsort` should be the number of elements in the array, so that you don't have to adjust it.

Comment: "I've tried replacing the [] with * but it doesn't make any difference," that is correct. In function arguments, it _literally_ makes no difference; you can even prototype with one or the other, or `[42]`. it all decays to a pointer.

Comment: For pity's sake, use white space.  Two nested `for` loops and a print statement on a single line is an abuse of the `return` key on your keyboard.  So is starting a new `for` loop on the same line as the `}` closing a prior `for` loop.  If the `return` key really doesn't work, get a replacement keyboard, and use a code formatter to format the code so that it is readable.  As it stands, it is horrendous!

Comment: Also, you have four lines: `if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])` —— `arr[j]   = arr[j] + arr[j+1],` —— `arr[j+1] = arr[j] - arr[j+1],` —— `arr[j]   = arr[j] - arr[j+1];` —— While it works, it is an abuse of the comma operator.  Use braces!  If your tutor is teaching you to code like this, I'm sorry, but you are being misguided.  If you invented this style on your own, I strongly recommend changing to a more orthodox style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the line "size /= sizeof(int)" - and the size is correct

```
    void bubblesort (int arr[], unsigned char size) {
    //    size /= sizeof(int);
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (unsigned char j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            arr[j]   = arr[j] + arr[j+1],
            arr[j+1] = arr[j] - arr[j+1],
            arr[j]   = arr[j] - arr[j+1];
    }
```

Test:

```
    1 2 0 
    3 4 
    6 7 5 
    9 8 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ~"[Thread 26424.0x564c exited with code 0]
```